# Программа должна сложить 2 числа и вывести результат в консоль. Но результат не выводится

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm, x86-64

```
section .data
X dd 4
Y dd 2
Z db 0
gg      equ $ - Z
section .text
global _start
_start:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ax, [X]
        add ax, [Y]
        mov [Z], ax
        mov ecx, gg
        int 0x80
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80
```

Comment: Вы знаете, что должно находиться в регистрах перед вызовом `int 0x80`?

Comment: тут недавно кто-то писал, что для 64-бит изменены системные вызовы, вместо int 0x80 что-то другое, ищите по сайту, это недавно было

Comment: @PavelGridin Я писал. Тому же человеку. Поэтому странно вдвойне. измениться они изменились, но старый способ тоже работает, если указатель умещается в 32 бита, правда не во всех вариантах конфигурации ядра.

Comment: в тексте программы слишком много ошибок на квадратный сантиметр, она не заработает даже если не учитывать использование старых системных вызовов.

Answer (score 0):

;Такой ответ

```
section .data
        sum db  4
section .text

global _start             ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov     ecx, '4'
    add     ecx, '2'
    sub    ecx, '0'

    mov     [sum], ecx
    mov     ecx, sum

    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ebx, 1          ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov     eax, 4          ;system call number (sys_write)
    int     0x80              ;call kernel

    mov     eax, 1          ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int     0x80            ;call kernel
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow и спасибо за ответ! Было бы полезно, если бы вы дополнили ответ с кодом хотя бы коротким объяснением, так принято на портале.

Comment: mov     ecx, '4'    ;Кладём 4 в ecx
add     ecx, '2'  ;Добавляем 2
    sub    ecx, '0'; Вычитаем 0, чтобы перевести в нужную систему счисления

    mov     [sum], ecx; Присваиваем результат вычислений sum в виде строки
    mov     ecx, sum ; Кладём строку в ecx, дальше просто вывод.